# How to access values of multidimensional JSON with jQuery and plot them on a Google Map

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional **JSON**, whose data I want to use to plot markers on my **Google Map**.

I use [this plugin for Jquery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) to work with my **Google Map**.

***With my current code I don't see any markers appear on my map. What could be causing this?***

Upon `init` event - the script should iterate over the **JSON** data, plot it on the map, and create/attach `info-boxes` with appropriate **HTML** markup for each value of each property to every marker.

My JSON looks like this:

```
[{product:{productName:"ProductA", productPrice:"19.99", productQuantity:"12", Lat:"53.573858", Lng:"45.985456"}},{product:{... repeat ...}}, {...}]
```

My jQuery's `$.each()` looks like this:

```
$('#map').gmap(mapOptions).bind('init', function () {
    $.post('myscript.php', function (json) {
        var theMarkers = json;
        $.each(theMarkers.product, function (i, object) {
            $.each(object, function (property, value) {
                $('#map').gmap('addMarker', {
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(object.Lat.value, object.Lng.value),
                    'bounds': true,
                    'icon': 'myicon.png'
                }).click(function () {
                    $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                        'content': '<h1>' + object.productName.value + '</h1>' + '<h2 style="color: grey">' + object.productPrice.value + '</h2><p style="color: green">' + object.productQuantity.value + '</p>'
                    }, this);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you include the JSON that has the `Lat` and `Lng` values .....

Comment: @ManseUK: I did. Just forgot to include them. I'll edit OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution:***

```
$('#map').gmap(mapOptions).bind('init', function(){
                    $.post('myscript.php', function(json){
                        var theMarkers = json;
                        $.each(theMarkers, function(i, element) {
                            $.each(element, function(object, dataMembers){
                                    $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(dataMembers.Lat), parseFloat(dataMembers.Lng)), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'myicon.png' } ).click(function(){                                
                                        $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<h1>'+dataMembers.productName+'</h1>'+'<h2 style="color: grey">'+dataMembers.productPrice+'</h2><p style="color: green">'+dataMembers.productQuantity+'</p>' }, this);
                                    }); 
                            });
                        });
                    }); 

                });
```

Answer (score 1):

The products are one level deeper than your current code assumes they are. So with

```
var theMarkers = json;
$.each(theMarkers, function (i, object) {
...
```

You will the get the objects containing your products, but theMarkers itself does not have any property called `product`.

You can test this with the following code:

```
$.each(theMarkers, function (i, o) {
  console.log(i, o);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this :

```
'position': new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(object.Lat.value), parseFloat(object.Lng.value)),
```

as `google.maps.LatLng` expects 2 `numbers` and you are passing `strings`.

[See the docs got LatLng here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip. It worked fine before with strings when I didn't have a multidimensional JSON on my hand.